# Disrupt flow with outer element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

I have a flexbox with elements that displays like this:

[image]

The question is: is there a way to disrupt the flow **from outside the flexbox**, so that the blocked element will move to the next position, like:

[image]

The flexbox is some kind of sorting box, so I can't place anything else inside then the elements to sort. Normally the columns are equal height, but sometimes I need the first column to be one shorter.

I've tried making the boxes `flow: left` and `display: inline-block` in various combinations, but I can't get it done.

```css
.container {
  width: 120px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 40px 0 0 100px;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 120px;
  height: 180px;
  background: pink;
}

.inbox {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 110px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexbox">
    <div class="inbox"> 1 </div>
    <div class="inbox"> 2 </div>
    <div class="inbox"> 3 </div>
    <div class="inbox"> 4 </div>
    <div class="inbox"> 5 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[And a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/but3a0q4/)

**Edit** I am only interested in the left bottom corner, so any kind of trick would do.

Comment: do you have *always* five `inbox` elements in there...

Comment: No, the are 18 or more, most times equal rows, only sometimes I need column 1 to be 1 box shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse` along with `column-reverse` *flex direction* and `justify-content: flex-end` you can get the configuration but not the *order* of the elements.

*Note that the order of the elements is the reverse of the markup though* - see demo below:

```css
.container {
  width: 120px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 40px 0 0 100px;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse; /* CHANGED */
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse; /* CHANGED */
  justify-content: flex-end; /* CHANGED */
  width: 120px;
  height: 180px;
  background: pink;
}

.inbox {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 110px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexbox">
    <div class="inbox"> 1 </div>
    <div class="inbox"> 2 </div>
    <div class="inbox"> 3 </div>
    <div class="inbox"> 4 </div>
    <div class="inbox"> 5 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thinking outside the box. Didn't even occur to me to reverse it. I can definetly work with this, only have to remember to reverse input at the beginning and output at the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, it could give you a basis for upgrades(like adding ajax in the equation). Hope this will be of some use to you!

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
x = rect.left;
w = rect.width;
var xa = document.getElementsByClassName('inbox');
var k = Array.from(xa).slice(-1).pop();
var rect2 = k.getBoundingClientRect();
x2 = rect2.left;
if(x+w > x2){
console.log(x + w , x2)
 k.style.left =+ (x) +"px";
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 120px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 40px 0 0 100px;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 120px;
  height: 180px;
  background: pink;
}

.inbox {
  position:relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 110px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="flexbox">
    <div class="inbox"> 1 </div>
    <div class="inbox"> 2 </div>
    <div class="inbox"> 3 </div>
    <div class="inbox"> 4 </div>
    <div class="inbox"> 5 </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this won't work for me. It's a sorting box, so the elements inside the flexbox will move around. Adding a fixed style to one requires also reversing it when the last inbox isn't the last inbox anymore.